# Comando ban pra bot no discord.js

Tags: javascript

Tô tentando fazer um comando ban pro meu bot discord.js, mas ele fala que eu não tenho permissão, mesmo sendo um dos administradores do servidor (nem o cara com ownership consegue).

```
if(comando === "ban") {
    if(!message.member.roles.some(r=>["Administrator"].includes(r.name)) )
      return message.reply("Você não tem permissões para usar este comando.");
    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    if(!member)
      return message.reply("Por favor, mencione um usuário válido.");
    if(!member.bannable) 
      return message.reply("Eu não posso banir este usuário! Ele pode ter um 
      cargo maior que o meu, ou eu não tenha permissão pra banir!");
    let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
    if(!reason) reason = "Forneça uma razão à esse banimento.";
    await member.ban(reason)
      .catch(error => message.reply("Desculpe ${message.author} não consegui banir o membro devido ao : ${error}"));
    message.reply("${member.user.tag} foi banido por ${message.author.tag} pelo motivo de: ${reason}`);
  }
```

Comment: Mas o [Administrator] já está marcado nesse código: if(!message.member.roles.some(r=>["Administrator"].includes(r.name)) ), onde devo colocá-lo, então?

Comment: O meu Discord está em inglês, e tá escrito "Administrator" na parte das roles.

Comment: Tenta criar uma nova role com um nome diferente pra testar e ver o resultado. Aqui, o mesmo código funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Fiz isso, criei uma role chamada Administrador, e deu certo. Mas queria saber se dá pra programar para que todos os cargos que tivessem a permissão de admin conseguissem executar o ban.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente, o erro está na role do usuário. O nome do grupo deve estar exatamente como no código `["Administrator"]`

É possível que, no seu discord, a role esteja como "Administra**dor**" e isso está causando a falta de permissão.

Answer (score 0):

No seu código, o bot está verificando se a pessoa tem uma role com o nome exato "Administrator", então provavelmente a sua role deve estar com outro nome.

Você pode colocar pro bot verificar se a pessoa tem a permissão Administrator com `if(!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return message.reply('Sem permissão')`

Ou com a permissão "BAN MEMBERS"
`if(!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('Sem permissão')`

Você deve apenas trocar a string de `hasPermission()`

Answer (score -1):

Para quem quer que o membro tenha permissões de admin para executar o comando é este comando aqui:

```
    if(!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR'))
    return message.reply("Você não tem permissões para usar este comando.");
```

Exemplo na imagem[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]